# Linq query as extension method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a query that is used multiple times across the application, and I want to make a function to simplify it.

I have tried to make it a IQueryable, ICollection, nothing worked.

This is what I want to do, basically:

This is a query:

```
dias = db.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS
        .Where(r =>
                (
                    r.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE.Count(
                            x => new[] { 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 }.Contains(x.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE_STATUS.COD_PARTICIPANTE_STATUS) &&
                            x.T_CLIENTES.IND_ATIVO == "s" &&
                            x.IND_ATIVO == "s") < ((r.IND_AVULSO == "s") ? 1 : r.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_FIXOS.NUM_MAXIMO_PARTICIPANTES)
                )
            )
    .Select(z => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(z.DAT_INICIO))
    .Distinct().ToList();
```

This part inside `r.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE.Count(` is the one used multiple times:

```
x => new[] { 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 }.Contains(x.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE_STATUS.COD_PARTICIPANTE_STATUS) &&
x.T_CLIENTES.IND_ATIVO == "s" &&
x.IND_ATIVO == "s"
```

I wanted to turn this into a function or something, just so I don't need to copy-paste this all the time.

This is what I have tried, with no success:

```
public static ICollection<T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE> Ativos(this ICollection<T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE> source, int codAgendamento)
    {
            return source               
            .Where(x => !(new[] { 3, 4, 9 }
                    .Contains(x.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE_STATUS.COD_PARTICIPANTE_STATUS)) &&
                    x.T_CLIENTES.IND_ATIVO == "s" &&
                    x.IND_ATIVO == "s" &&
                    x.COD_AGENDAMENTO == codAgendamento)
            .ToList();
    }
```

Then using the function like this:

```
dias = db.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS
        .Where(r =>
                (
                    r.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE.Ativos(r.COD_AGENDAMENTO).Count() < ((r.IND_AVULSO == "s") ? 1 : r.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_FIXOS.NUM_MAXIMO_PARTICIPANTES)
                )
        )
        .Select(z => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(z.DAT_INICIO))
        .Distinct().ToList();
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Error CS1061  'ICollection'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Ativos' and no extension method
>   'Ativos' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ICollection' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What can be done?

Comment: Please left align your code next time

Comment: The reason you're getting into issue like this, is because like your posts, your code is not easily read, if you want help you should take the time to write a well formulated post, so people can understand it easily, no one want to waste extra time figuring out things that could have been solved by better communcation

Comment: Now to help you out: 1. Why are you creating a Db context in your extension method you do not use it. 2.  You cannot call your extension method, you to create an Expression to pass it into the where instead

Comment: I was using it at first, forgot to remove.

Comment: instead of a extension method create `Expression<Func< T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS, Bool>>` to as a where filter with your data to pass to the queryable. alternatively you can create two queries and join them

Comment: Do you have any references for the first option? I haven't seen this before and I don't know what keywords to search for

Comment: I'm on my phone right now it's hard to provide an example. But take the return type of the where and make a method and put the lambda in there. So you can just reuse it

Answer (score 1):

You could store your lambda expression in a variable or property:

```
Expression<Func<T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE, bool>> exp = x => new[] { 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 }.Contains(x.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE_STATUS.COD_PARTICIPANTE_STATUS) &&
x.T_CLIENTES.IND_ATIVO == "s" &&
x.IND_ATIVO == "s"
```

and then use it in any expersion:

```
dias = db.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS
        .Where(
            r.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE.Count(exp) < ((r.IND_AVULSO == "s") ? 1 : r.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_FIXOS.NUM_MAXIMO_PARTICIPANTES)
        )
        .Select(z => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(z.DAT_INICIO))
        .Distinct().ToList();
```

Is this what you need? This way you can reuse your lambda expression. You could store it in a static read only property.

If you need some parameters you could use a method instead:

```
Expression<Func<T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE, bool>> exp(int[] group){
    return  x => group.Contains(x.T_AGENDA_AGENDAMENTOS_CLIENTES_PARTICIPANTE_STATUS.COD_PARTICIPANTE_STATUS) &&
     x.T_CLIENTES.IND_ATIVO == "s" &&
     x.IND_ATIVO == "s"
}
```

Hope it helps!